# Keeping track of all Class instances Java

Tags: java, class, oop

So I created a class with a constructor and I'm instantiating them in my code on different conditions, I'm using UUID's as id.
`new Arena(....)`

So how do I get all those instances of Arena, and maybe remove some of them in case it's needed.

Comment: Make the constructor private and create the instances using a static factory method, storing each instance created in a collection.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Normally it's up to the code creating and using the instances to release their reference to them when done (which is all that's required for Java to clean them up).